# Is there a way to use Google Sheets filter views on IOS?

Tags: google-apps, google

I made a sheet in Google Sheets on the desktop with several filter views. Then I opened the sheet in the Google Sheets app on my iPhone. In the iPhone app menu, there is an option to create a filter, but I don't see any way to access my existing filter views.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google docs currently list this as not supported on iOS:

> Note: Filter views are only available on a computer. See the FILTER article for info about the function.

Source:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en&oco=2

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use DESKTOP VERSION of the Google Sheet WEB APP on any mobile platform.
Just open your google sheet in a browser, and switch to a desktop version for that page - you will get the FULL FUNCTIONALITY of Google Sheets on mobile.
TIP: if you want to zoom the whole page, do this on some "white area" - the top bar with menu or the context menu (tap-and-hold) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: Do you have a citation for this or are you simply speculating?

Comment: Tried myself, then asked support.